# How do I implement Map.getOrCreate? (object caching pattern)

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Often I find myself following this cache some object in a map pattern:

```
myMap = new Map<string, MyThing>;
getThing(key: string): MyThing {
  let thing = this.myMap.get(key);
  if (thing !== undefined) return thing;

  thing = new MyThing();
  this.myMap.set(key, thing);
  return thing;
}
```

I want to generalize this to something like:

```
getOrCreate(this.myMap, key, MyThing);
```

or

```
this.myMap.getOrCreate(key, MyThing);
```

**Initial implementation idea:**

```
export function getOrCreate<K, V>(map: Map<K, V>, key: K, objConstructor: () => V) {
  let v = map.get(key);
  if (v !== undefined) return v;

  v = objConstructor();
  map.set(key, v);
  return v;
}
```

1. Am I re-inventing the wheel? Does TypeScript or the ES6 library already have something like this? (I don't see a method for this in Map)
2. Also, I want to be able to pass a general function or an object constructor.
   How do I determine if I need to execute `new objConstructor()` or just `objConstructor()`?
   What would the objConstructor type be if the function supports both?
   `() => V | Constructor???() => V`
   Or should I pass in `MyThing.constructor` as an argument; will calling that be equivalent to `new MyThing()`?
   Or maybe just `if (objConstructor.constructor) new objConstructor();`?
3. Is it good practice to modify Map by defining `Map.prototype.getOrCreate`?
4. If I were to modify Map.prototype, does that affect maps created with the native `{}` instead of `new Map()` or is that a different kind of Map?

---

**EDIT:** Issues with passing a constructor with a generic signature.

```
getOrCreate(myMap, key, AsyncSubject);
```

> Argument of type 'typeof AsyncSubject' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => AsyncSubject'.

You can't do `AsyncSubject<MyThing>`, that's a syntax error.

`AsyncSubject as any` works, but is there a way to fix the getOrCreate signature and maintain type-checking?

This implementation passes type-checking:

```
export function getOrCreate<K, V>(map: Map<K, V>, key: K, constructor: ( () => V ) | Object) {
  let v = map.get(key);
  if (v !== undefined) return v;

  if (constructor instanceof Object) v = new (<any>constructor)();
  else v = constructor();
  map.set(key, v);
  return v;
}
```

Is using **Object** as a type like this good practice?

Of course `() => new AsyncSubject<MyThing>()` works, but this is verbose.

*TypeScript 2.0.3*

Comment: 1. no 2. you don't - always pass a function that creates a value somehow, you should not care how. 3. no 4. DON'T (but `{}` is definitely not a `Map`)

Comment: You shouldn't test whether  `get` returns `undefined` but rather check `map.has(key)`. Otherwise, I can only second zerkms.

Comment: @Bergi I do that to avoid an extra function call. The signature in **lib.es6.d.ts** is `get(key: K): V | undefined;`